# get_template_directory_uri() not returning string

Tags: php, wordpress

I am hoping someone can help I am fairly green when it comes to WP.

I am linking to images using `get_template_directory_uri()` however it is working fine on my **header.php** and **footer.php** but not on **page-{slug}.php** pages. I have tried this and `get_bloginfo('template_directory')`. Also this is being developed on MAMP localhost.

Both are below however both are returning `<img class="arrow" src="assets/arrow_white.png" alt="down">`

```
<img class="arrow" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/arrow_white.png" alt="down"/>
<a href="#"><img class="arrow" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/arrow_white.png" alt="down"/></a>
```

Comment: If not a string...what is it returning?

Comment: ii is not returning anything. I am getting '<img class="arrow" src="assets/arrow_white.png" alt="down">' when it should be '<img class="arrow" src="localhost:8888/website-name/wp-content/themes/theme-name/assets/arrow_white.png" alt="down">'

Answer (score 0):

It was a template hierarchy issue I had a duplicate and it was using the other template that did not have the additions.

Stupid mistake!!!